# debugging fopen in C

Tags: c, debugging, fopen

Im new to C and trying to read a file using the fopen command as follows:

```
 FILE *f = fopen (argv[1], "rb" );

         if(!f)
        {
            printf("ERROR! Unable to open file \n");
            fclose(f);
            return 1;
        }
```

The file Im trying to read is "somefile.dat"

When I run this I get the following in the console

```
  ERROR! Unable to open file
```

So f is null, but how do I debug this? I mean where do I start to look for the problem?

Thanks

---

UPDATE:

I tried te various suggestions below and found that the problem was it couldnt locate the file.

Im using XCode to run the program and XCode runs the executable in a different directory than where the files are placed so it couldnt find the file. I gave it a hard path and it worked.

The problem now is how to provide XCode the correct path to the file?
Where does XCode run the executable?

Comment: `#include <errno.h>` and use `perror` to find out why it failed?

Comment: check the permissions for `"somefile.dat"`

Comment: check the location of `somefile.dat`, check what your current working directory is, it might not be what you think.

Comment: Don't use `fclose` if `fopen` fails, as you're sending a NULL pointer to the function (result is undefined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, hardcode your file's name. If the problem is gone, then the problem lies with your using argv.
- Second, make sure the file exists. Try to open it in your explorer. Maybe it's somehow locked.
- Thirs, use [perror](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/) for a more descriptive error.

Hope you'll find your problem with these.

Comment: perror helped me diagnose the problem. The file was in a different directory thanks to Xcode's weird setup of working directories

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you should do to debug this:

- Add `printf` to see what's inside the `argv[1]`
- Make sure that the printed value matches the expected file name; if necessary, change the command line to look for an absolute path, i.e. `~myuser/somefile.dat` or `c:\myproject\somefile.dat` rather than `somefile.dat`
- Check that a file with that name exists in the current directory
- Check that the user under which your program runs (usually, that's your user) has access permissions to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of below possible reason can be

1) Path is incorrect

2) Permission of file somefile.dat are not correct so fopen fails

You can use errno to check what creating problem.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/